# Specify object definition to spring.net XmlApplicationContext at runtime

Tags: c#, spring.net

I am new to Spring.Net, until now I was defining the xml file where I had defined all the object's definition and then created the XMLApplicationContext. Now I have to support plugins which can be inserted into XMLApplicationContext. I tried the following,

```
context.ConfigureObject (inObject, inName);
(context as XmlApplicationContext).ObjectFactory.RegisterSingleton (inName, inObject);
```

using this the object is registered into the context at runtime, however I am not able to provide the object definition where I can specify objects properties and its ref. The ref here is to an object id which is in common config xml which was used to create XMLApplicationContext. Is this possible?

Also is there any way that after creating the XMLApplicationContext we can extend it for new config xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the container for the previously-registered object's ObjectDefinition and from that you should be able to gather the xml-registered object id for you to the use as your ref info.

Comment: Yes, I did it that way previously, now I have my plugins defining their own object definition which I register in XMLApplicationContext. Thanks!